# javaScript clear image source not working

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to convert a div with text and image into a single image then setting that image as my image source but the image is getting copied multiple times or getting error and code not working.

I am getting the text from `textarea` and then setting that text on the above of image and then converting that text and image into a single image by using html5canavs. Code is working fine but the issue is image is getting copied multiple times and if I am trying to clear the image it is not working.

Here's the image of how it is looking after overlapping multiple times.[image: Image Priview]

Here's my code

```js
window.onload = function() {
  
  }

  function myFunction() {
    var v = document.getElementById("mTextArea").value;
    document.getElementById("wow").innerHTML = v;

    html2canvas(document.getElementById("imagewrap"), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        theCanvas = canvas;

        canvas.className = "html2canvas";
        var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        // document.body.removeChild("container2"); <<---Throwing Error
        document.getElementById("img_prev").src = image;
      },
      useCORS: true
    });
  }
```

```css
*{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
#container1{
    float: left;
}
#container2{
    float: right;
}
#mImage{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}

.desc {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 1px;
    left: 30px;
}
.outer, .wrap, .html2canvas, .image_text {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
.wrap {
text-align: center;
}
#imagewrap {
    position: relative;
background-color: white;
}
#wow {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25pt;
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
    display: block;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <title>Social Poster</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Social Poster</h1>
        <div id="container1">
            <textarea name="inputT" id="mTextArea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            <button id="mButton" onclick="myFunction()">Click ME!</button>
        </div>
        <div id="container2">
              <div class="outer">
                <div id="imagewrap" class="wrap" style="border: solid;">
                  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQ2w0Uf5u-qRiqYZVXmHukxNQxPENtwoEqh2qBpj871sojoaePh&usqp=CAU" id="img_prev" width="500" />
                  <span id="wow">WOW!</span>
                </div>
              </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Couple of things to note in your code. (0) `theCanvas` isn't declared anywhere. (1) your image is changing size. At init, its 200x200. After 1 click, it's 506x510. After the 2nd, it's 506x514 then 506x518. (2) The first time you click, you're drawing over an 'empty' image. The next time you click, the image now contains text from the first click. Since the size of the image is changing, you get the text drawn at the same place while the image is shrunken - this gives the effect you're seeing here.

Comment: the (0) was a mistake I forgot to remove that, I have seen that in a tutorial. I know it is drawing over the image again and again but I thought that changing img_prev source will change the source of the image, can you guide me on how can I correctly change the source of the image?

Comment: what do you want the source of the image to be? I'd have thought that you'd want the click handler to make sure the image source was the original one, then do the html2canvas step, then set the background image. Repeating this will ensure you start with a fresh image each time and so each time you clicked was just like the first time.

Comment: Actually, I want every time when I click a button the text from the text area get overlayed on top of image and then convert text and image into one single image and load that Image into the img_prev.

Comment: For better understanding think it's a page where the user can put text on his image and save it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rendering the image ontop of its self causing the feedback effect.

Just use two images. Showing the background and text when you click render and when the result has rendered hide the original background and text just showing the result image.

Move the border out of the rendered image to stop the shrinking background.

### Example

```js
mButton.addEventListener("click",createImage);

function createImage() {
  // show text and background image
  wow.textContent = mTextArea.value;
  wow.classList.remove("hide");
  backgroundImage.classList.remove("hide");
  
  // hide prev rendered image
  resultImage.classList.add("hide");
  
  // render to canvas
  html2canvas(imagewrap, {
    onrendered(canvas) {
      // hide background and text image
      backgroundImage.classList.add("hide");
      backgroundImage.classList.add("hide");
      
      // show rendered image
      resultImage.classList.remove("hide");
      resultImage.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    },
    useCORS: true
  });
}
```

```css
*{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
#container1{
    float: left;
}
#container2{
    float: right;
}
#mImage{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}

.desc {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 1px;
    left: 30px;
}
.outer, .wrap, .html2canvas, .image_text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
}
#imagewrap {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
}
#wow {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25pt;
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
    display: block;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
.resultBorder {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

<h1>Social Poster</h1>
<div id="container1">
    <textarea name="inputT" id="mTextArea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <button id="mButton" >Create Image!</button>
</div>
<div id="container2">
      <div class="outer resultBorder">
        <div id="imagewrap" class="wrap" >
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQ2w0Uf5u-qRiqYZVXmHukxNQxPENtwoEqh2qBpj871sojoaePh&usqp=CAU" id="backgroundImage" width="500" />
          <img class="hide" id="resultImage"></img>
          <span id="wow">WOW!</span>
        </div>
      </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem - Multiple images** --  why?

After first click it captures the `div` into `canvas`.You can clearly see there is some **border** outside image. So after you are setting the image in the div to the "**canvas created image**" border will remain and the div captured into image will have inturn the border as its like screenshot of it.

**Solution:**

Remove the border and avoid spacing

**Problem - Text over Text** -- why?

You are setting the value of span with id "wow" to the value of text area whenever you click the "click me" button and then you are doing `html2canvas` which will make an image of div since you have span inside div with text it will also be there in the canvas.After canvas is generated you are setting the src of image to `canvas.toDataURL()`. When you again click on "click me" with different text , it will place the text on current image(which already has some previous text)

**Solution:**

Set the text of the span with id="wow" after `img.src=canvas.toDateURL()`

```js
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("wow").innerHTML =""
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("imagewrap"), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var image = canvas.toDataURL();      
      document.getElementById("img_prev").src = image
      document.getElementById("wow").innerHTML =
      document.getElementById("mTextArea").value;
      },
      useCORS: true
    });
  }
```

```css
*{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
#container1{
    float: left;
}
#container2{
    float: right;
}
#mImage{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}

.desc {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 1px;
    left: 30px;
}
.outer, .wrap, .html2canvas, .image_text {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
.wrap {
text-align: center;
}
#imagewrap {
    position: relative;
background-color: white;
}
#wow {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25pt;
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
    display: block;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <title>Social Poster</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Social Poster</h1>
        <div id="container1">
            <textarea name="inputT" id="mTextArea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            <button id="mButton" onclick="myFunction()">Click ME!</button>
        </div>
        <div id="container2">
              <div class="outer">
                <div id="imagewrap" class="wrap" >
                  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQ2w0Uf5u-qRiqYZVXmHukxNQxPENtwoEqh2qBpj871sojoaePh&usqp=CAU" id="img_prev" width="500" />
                  <span id="wow">WOW!</span>
                </div>
              </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, by this surely it is hiding the issue but didn't really solve it the image is still getting overlayed multiple times and on saving that text didn't get saved with it. So it defeats the whole purpose of doing it.

Comment: if it saves with it , there is a problem of text over text problem bruh...what do you want the desired result to be!!

Comment: I am sorry if I was unable to explain clearly English is not my mother tongue so I am not good at it, by the way, I got the answer as I wanted. Thanks for taking the time and answering.